# Block rss in Magento

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento-1.9

I need to block this URL: `https://example.com/rss/catalog/notifystock/` on my site.

I wrote following code to block:

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php/?)?rss/ - [L,R=403]
```

but its block the following URL: `https://example.com/index.php/rss/catalog/notifystock/`

It has not blocked this URL: `https://example.com/rss/catalog/notifystock/`

Can anyone Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule rss - [F]
```

What that should do is block access to any page that has rss in its URL. You could also use:

```
<FilesMatch "rss$">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

So if a file matches rss, then it will deny access to everyone. However, if you're using Apache 2.4, then it would be:

```
<FilesMatch "rss$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```